# Chat and VOIP Application

Tags: android, xmpp, voip, sip, openfire

I have successfully installed the Openfire XMPP server and built an Android app to text chat, 
How can I implement VOIP functionality to my application? 
Can  this be done by connecting openfire with a SIP server?

Can someone guide me?

Comment: I have same requirement. May you please suggest me how you have implemented and test this. I need to implement VOIP in iOS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a plan to use Openfire, you need to install Openfire SIP Phone plug-in and Client Control  plug-in to your Openfire Server. Then, you have to setup another SIP server for SIP services ( Because, Openfire Server only allows XMPP services). I'm using 3CX Phone System server software for SIP services. It's working fine. Finally, you need to merge the SIP server with Openfire server. You can find out these information from this link with screenshots: http://www.3cx.com/forums/how-to-integrate-3cx-with-openfire-xmpp-jabber-server-9951.html.

OR

Another solution is,

You can use IceWarp server. It's MULTI-PROTOCOL server. However, you need to install another SIP server for VoIP services. Because,  IceWarp server only supports MULTI-PROTOCOLs and doesn't provide multi-protocol services.  So, you need to provide VOIP provider/service for enable VoIP services in IceWarp server (can use 3CX Phone System). There is a option to configure the VoIP service in IceWarp. For further information, www.icewarp.com/downloads/documentation/server/

Answer (score 3):

If you chose XMPP as the IM protocol, then it'd be logical to use Jingle for voice and video communcations. I remember that Openfire supports Jingle, so you just have to implement it in your client app. Out of the box Openfire gives you p2p voice/video. If you need calls to/from PSTN and/or SIP domain then you need some extra. It should be kind of jingle<->SIP gateway. Perhaps you'll be able to make this using SIP Phone Plugin together with Openfire Media Proxy. If you're looking for SIP between client and server then just use Openfire SIP Phone Plugin.

Comment: I have used IceWarp, and it seems it supports for XMPP and SIP voip,

Comment: If I understand you right and you're talking about IceWarp client (I can't find android client on their web site) then install Openfire SIP Phone Plugin to your Openfire Server. It's intended to provide SIP interface for clients.